# Hide Scrollbar when Printing highchart from export menu

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to hide scrollbar when `printing chart` while `exporting`.
I am able to hide `scrollbar` when exporting `image & pdf` but not able to hide it while choosing `print chart` option.

I have tried `exporting.chartOptions` configuration like below

```
      chart_options.exporting.chartOptions = {
        xAxis : [{
          categories: timeline,
          min: 0,
          minRange: timeline.length-1,
          max: timeline.length-1
        }],
        scrollbar:{
          enabled: false
      }
```

It is working fine with other exporting options but not in `print chart` option.

https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/gdv7oz9w/

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS Printing - `@media` Rule

```
@media print {
  .highcharts-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

By dynamically changing the `max` property of `xAxis`

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);    
chart.xAxis[0].options.max = undefined;
chart.render();
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/fcr49j0g/3/)

Comment: This will not work with https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/gdv7oz9w/ as I want to remove scroll bar and print every data points.

Comment: @HarishSharma print after scroll issue fixed

Comment: yes it is fixed. I got the way to fix it with the working demo you attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforePrint` and `afterPrint` events to change a chart:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        beforePrint: function() {
            this.update({
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            });
        },
        afterPrint: function() {
            this.update({
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ae905yfx/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.afterPrint

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.beforePrint

Comment: Scrollbar is particularly on axis and this solution is not working here. https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/gdv7oz9w/